# Images from Imgur lose resolution when scaled down

Tags: support, images, imgur

In [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32896/list-of-duplicates-questions-defaced-or-vandalised/32900#32900) Maths Meta SE thread, I noticed that the image linked in my answer was blurry, even though it was being scaled down to a lower resolution. For comparison, check out the images below:

[image]
[image]

The left image is the original image, and the right image is the scaled image, where both images are scaled down to medium (320x320 pixel resolution of thumbnail).

I've also tried using HTML to resize the images, but the Imgur image didn't show up that time, so I can't check how that affects it.

Why is this happening to my images? Is the compression happening on Imgur's servers or the SE servers?

Comment: Possibly cuz the file size is to big.

Comment: Workaround is to use the "large", not "medium" thumbnail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9glEl.png still much smaller than original but with good quality.

Answer (score 1):

The compression is done on imgur's side, but since it's treated as a graphic image, not as SVG, it can't possibly retain the text quality when compressing high-resolution screenshots.

To preserve the quality, lower the screenshot resolution on your device, each device has its own way, but I'm pretty sure it's doable on all modern mobile devices.

In case you take the screenshot on a PC, you'll have to lower the screen resolution itself.

Comment: "it can't possibly retain the text quality when compressing high resolution screenshots" of course it's possible, the question demonstrates this by posting a less blurry scaled-down version of the original image.

Comment: @RyanM the images in the question appear to be screenshots of the scaled screenshots, not original so of course the quality will be terrible. The original can be found only [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9glE.png), OP did not link to it anywhere. It's a huge 2046x1280 image, which means x4 ratio than what we see here.

Comment: Yep, the images in the posts are not the originals. What actually happened was that I zoomed the screen in quite a bit and then took the screenshot. I was thinking this would increase the image quality, but I didn't expect it to have that much of an effect.

Comment: Ah, I see.  For comparison, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8FyN.png) is the original from your link, scaled down to 320x200 in MS Paint.  It's arguably less blurry than the [original scaled-down version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9glEm.png), but that might just be a stylistic choice with the scaling algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

As U11-Forward has mentioned, the file size is too big. If I use a different image which has a smaller file size, the problem disappears.

[image]
[image]

In the two images above, there is no obvious loss of resolution.

Comment: No, that's a photo, not a screenshot as in your question. I think the difference lies there.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiyZv.jpg), simply uploaded without modification and turned into a comment - looks very sharp and uncompressed to me. It's 1440x2560 and a 1.5MB jpeg.

Comment: It's probably a combination of the original screenshot having text, which becomes more noticeably blurry when it's scaled down, and the fact that the screenshot with text is a larger file size (which correlates with [Shadow's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358611/images-from-imgur-lose-resolution-when-scaled-down#comment1197385_358615) about the screenshot having a higher resolution.)